# New USB NVMe drive does not show up in lsblk, dmesg says 'Unit Not Ready', Any Suggestions?

Tags: mount, 20.04, usb-drive, nvme

I've got a Brand New ORICO TCM3-C3 NVMe M.2 SSD enclosure which I am using with a WD Blue WDS500G2B0B-00YS70 500Gb NVMe ssd (also new)

When I plug it in I get the usual ping of a USB device being recognised but when I run `lsblk` of `sudo fdisk -l` It does not show up.

`dmesg` gives the following:

```
[  851.445300] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  851.466378] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0583, bcdDevice= 2.09
[  851.466383] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  851.466386] usb 2-2: Product: External HDD
[  851.466388] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: External USB3.0
[  851.466391] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: DD56419883969
[  851.471581] scsi host0: uas
[  851.472404] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     External USB3.0           0209 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  851.473635] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  859.632889] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unit Not Ready
[  859.632896] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[  859.632903] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[  859.633498] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  859.633504] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[  859.633510] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[  859.633938] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  859.633941] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[  859.633946] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[  859.634336] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[  859.634339] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0-byte physical blocks
[  859.634699] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[  859.634821] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[  859.634828] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  859.635177] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (0 byt>
[  859.654051] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unit Not Ready
[  859.654060] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[  859.654069] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[  859.654498] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  859.654505] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[  859.654512] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[  859.654950] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  859.654956] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[  859.654965] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[  859.656373] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
```

I tried this on my laptop running Ubuntu 20.04 kernel 5.4.0-37-generic
and on my raspberry pi4 running the new 64bit pi OS it had basically the same `dmesg`

Any ideas about if/how I can get this device to work?

Comment: What do you expect it to look like in `lsblk`? Is the output exactly the same with and without the USB to NVME adapter connected? How new is the computer (can we expect the USB hardware of the computer to manage it? Does it work in some other computer?

Comment: `lsblk` is unchanged when I plug in the USB. I've tried it in 3 different Linux boxes and 2 windows PCs now and I get a similar thing with all of them they notice there is a new USB device plugged in but it does not show up as storage. In Windows it appears in the device manager as an 'External USB3.0 SCSI Disk Device' - ah it shows up in the windows disk manager with an option to initialize the disk, not in Gparted though. What would the way to initialize the disk with linux?

Comment: Sorry - missed your point about computer i'm using - I'm running a pretty recent laptop with full usb3.0 support and update firmware (lenovo thinkpad X1 yoga 2nd edition). The target system for this device to run on once/if I can get it working is a new Raspberry Pi 4b 8Gb

Comment: Update: Trying to initialise the disk with the windows disk manager yields an error: 'The Request Failed due to a fatal device hardware error'

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information. You have tested the USB to NVME adapter in many up to date computers. I think the problem is that there is a compatibility problem, the USB to NVME adapter cannot be managed by the computers. It is difficult for me to understand if it is a hardware or software problem. Usually this kind of hardware devices are tested (to make sure they work) with Windows and/or MacOS. Otherwise they will be difficult to sell. Could it be that you can download a driver for it and install the driver in Windows?

Comment: There were not any specific windows drivers to download either automatically by windows or on the manufacturer's site - they do claim Linux compatibility. 
Product page: http://www.orico.cc/us/product/detail/4039.html
The WD NVMe drive i'm using is the 500Gb version of the 250Gb one they are using in the promotional shot for the device so I had high hopes for a smooth start!

Comment: Maybe the hardware is damaged. If it is new, you should be able to get a replacement or the money back.

Comment: By the way, I have a couple of USB3 to SATA adapters. They work very well for me to use SSDs (2.5" with SATA interface) that are quite cheap nowadays to run portable operating systems (persistent live or installed).

Comment: Could be damage but I have two of them that are behaving the same way which makes it seem less likely (was planning two identical pi home servers one for me and one at my parents place). My understanding was that SATA could be a bottleneck over USB3.0 and that NVMe could acheive higher speeds even over USB3.0, plus I could always reuse the drives later in a system with PCIe. But apparently things are still a bit buggy :( Thanks for engaging. I emailed the manufacturer to see what they have to say.

Comment: It could even be such that the adapter works with a 250GB drive, but not with a 500GB drive. I have seen something similar with an old USB to SATA adapter.

Answer (score 2):

RTFM Richard RTFM - I picked up sata WD blues not NVMe ones
With the correct SSD type for the adapter (NVMe) this works fine.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience :-/ Please let us know, how you solve this problem (the NVME route or SATA route) ...

Comment: I didn't RTFM because I don't know which. I picked up an NVMe drive and an adapter and just expected it to work (it does on my old NAS with an m.2 to PCIe adapter). What influences whether a drive is recognized?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with an ssd (nvme) that had been running Ubuntu. The boot information became corrupted during an upgrade to 20.04.  I'm assuming the mbr was damaged, as well.
After putting the ssd in an adapter, I couldn't access the drive from any of 3 linux computers (including the one I'd removed the ssd from).

But I was able to recover all of the data in the other partitions using a Macbook Pro with osxfuse and ext4fuse both installed thru homebrew.  This is making me think the Linux drivers are not compatible with the adapter.

If you have access to a Mac, you may be able to at least see what's on the drive, and give you a hint at what's wrong.  HtH.